# Assigning model values to javascript variables based on condition (in Razor)

Tags: javascript, razor

I am trying to assign a value from a Model into a JavaScript variable. But I have to check a condition before doing so.

Normally, I can assign values using this statement in script : `var quantity = '@Model.Quantity'`. It works, but I don't know how to do this inside an if loop, like-

```
<script>
    @if (Model.Count == 0)
    {
        var quantity = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        var quantity = '@Model.Quantity';
    }
</script>
```

But the statement inside the loop will be rendered as C#. So how do I achieve this ? I have to store the quantity into a JavaScript variable inside `if` loop.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
<script>
    @if (Model.Count == 0)
    {
        @: var quantity = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        @: var quantity = '@Model.Quantity';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as follow:-

```
<script>
    var quantity = 0;
    @if(Model.Count > 0)
    {
       quantity = 'Model.Quantity';
    }
</script>
```